# Evaluate $ \int_{R} \; \ln(\frac{x-y}{x+y})\;dxdy$ where $R$ is a triangular region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $$\iint_{R} \; \ln\left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)\;dxdy$$ where $R$ is the triangular region with vertices $(1,0), (4,-3)$ and $(4,1)$

My work. I tried using the transformation 
$u=x-y$, $v=x+y$ with $|J|=1/2$
which changed the given integral as follows:
$$1/2\iint_{R_{1}} \; \ln\left(\frac{u}{v}\right) \; dudv$$ where $R_{1}$ is triangle formed with vertices $(1,1)$, $(3,5)$, $(7,1)$

But this was no help at all since the integration is still very difficult...
I can't think of any other transformation as well. Please help me

Comment: Maybe try splitting $ln(\frac{u}{v}) = ln(u) - ln(v)$ and then use the linearity of integrals, and set $ln(.) = t$ for each integral?

Comment: You could try a transformation that maps to a right triangle.

Comment: @learning it would still be too lengthy

Comment: @PhilipHoskins I think it needs a transformation that can be integrated with the ln term by further substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. The integral now is
$$\frac{1}{2}\iint_{R_1} \; \ln(u/v)\;dudv=\frac{1}{2}\int_{v=1}^5 \int_{u=(1+v)/2}^{8-v}  \ln(u/v)\;dudv\\=
\frac{1}{2}\int_{v=1}^5 \left[u\ln(u/v)-u\right]_{u=(1+v)/2}^{8-v}dv.$$
Can you take it from here? Actually the [final result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2*int(int(ln(u%2Fv),u%3D(1%2Bv)%2F2..8-v),v%3D1..5);) is not very pretty.